# Coordinate of a point on cylindrical helix with TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I have a cylindrical helix and two points on it (say A and B). I want to draw a line from A to B. How can I parse this coordinate in TiKz? Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
 view={-20}{-20},
 axis line style = ultra thick,
 axis lines=middle,
 zmax=80,
  xmax=2,
   ymax=2,
 height=12cm,
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 ztick=\empty,
 clip=false,
 x label style={at={(axis cs:2,0.051)},anchor=north},
   xlabel={$y$},
 y label style={at={(axis cs:0.05,2)},anchor=north},
   ylabel={$x$},
 z label style={at={(axis cs:0.075,0,80)},anchor=north},
   zlabel={$z$},
]
\addplot3+[domain=0:11*pi,samples=500,samples y=0,black,no marks,ultra thick] 
({sin(deg(x))}, 
{cos(deg(x))}, 
{6*x/(pi)})
node[circle,scale=0.2,fill,pos=0.05]{}
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.15]{} % coordinate (A)
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.515]{}; % coordinate (B)
%\draw (A)--(B);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `name` on the `node`

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
 view={-20}{-20},
 axis line style = ultra thick,
 axis lines=middle,
 zmax=80,
  xmax=2,
   ymax=2,
 height=12cm,
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 ztick=\empty,
 clip=false,
 x label style={at={(axis cs:2,0.051)},anchor=north},
   xlabel={$y$},
 y label style={at={(axis cs:0.05,2)},anchor=north},
   ylabel={$x$},
 z label style={at={(axis cs:0.075,0,80)},anchor=north},
   zlabel={$z$},
]
\addplot3+[domain=0:11*pi,samples=500,samples y=0,black,no marks,ultra thick] 
({sin(deg(x))}, 
{cos(deg(x))}, 
{6*x/(pi)})
node[circle,scale=0.2,fill,pos=0.05]{}
node [name=A,circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.15]{} % coordinate (A)
node [name=B,circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.515]{}; % coordinate (B)
\draw[red] (A)--(B);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[
 view={-20}{-20},
 axis line style = ultra thick,
 axis lines=middle,
 zmax=80,
  xmax=2,
   ymax=2,
 height=12cm,
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 ztick=\empty,
 clip=false,
 x label style={at={(axis cs:2,0.051)},anchor=north},
   xlabel={$y$},
 y label style={at={(axis cs:0.05,2)},anchor=north},
   ylabel={$x$},
 z label style={at={(axis cs:0.075,0,80)},anchor=north},
   zlabel={$z$},
]
\addplot3+[domain=0:11*pi,samples=500,samples y=0,black,no marks,ultra thick] 
({sin(deg(x))}, 
{cos(deg(x))}, 
{6*x/(pi)})
node[circle,scale=0.2,fill,pos=0.05]{}
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.15] (A) {} % coordinate (A)
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0.515] (B) {}; % coordinate (B)
\draw[red,ultra thick] (A)--(B);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]